# Getting the whole numbers from formula field in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, field, pass-by-reference, formula, assign

How can i get the whole numbers from one data and assign it to formula field in crystal report? And the remaining will be assign to another formula field.

Ex;

Data = 102.80

- Formula#1 = 102 // i get the whole number and assign to Formula#1.
- Formula#2 = 80  // then the decimal point now assign to another formula field called Formula#2

Pls give me some idea, thanks! have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In `Formula1`

```
ToNumber(Split(CStr(Data),".")[1])
```

In `Formula2`

```
ToNumber(Split(CStr(Data),".")[2])
```

Comment: By converting to a string you're going to be truncating the decimal portion and the value will lose precision. It's probably better to do this strictly numerically with the `round()` function.

Comment: @Ryan but do we get decimal part using `round()` function?

Comment: You can get the whole value with `round()` and the decimal portion by subtracting that from the original value.